# devise.registrations.reasons in yml files is deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just updated to Rails 3.2 and after starting WEBrick I get the following error:

```
[DEVISE] devise.registrations.reasons in yml files is deprecated, please use devise.registrations.signed_up_but_REASON instead. The default values are:

en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: 'A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account.'
      signed_up_but_inactive: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated.'
      signed_up_but_locked: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked.'



[DEVISE] devise.registrations.inactive_signed_up in yml files is deprecated, please use devise.registrations.signed_up_but_REASON instead. The default values are:

en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: 'A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account.'
      signed_up_but_inactive: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated.'
      signed_up_but_locked: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked.'
```

In my devise locale file I have another lines:

```
  registrations:
      signed_up: 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
      inactive_signed_up: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is %{reason}.'
      updated: 'You updated your account successfully.'
      destroyed: 'Bye! Your account was successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon.'
      reasons:
        inactive: 'inactive'
        unconfirmed: 'unconfirmed'
        locked: 'locked'
```

Sorry I'm a Rails beginner. What exactly I have to change? And How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just come across this too. This seems to work fine:

In config > locales > devise.en.yml > about line 36 change the registrations block to:

```
registrations:
    signed_up: 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
    updated: 'You updated your account successfully.'
    destroyed: 'Bye! Your account was successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon.'
    signed_up_but_unconfirmed: 'A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account.'
    signed_up_but_inactive: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated.'
    signed_up_but_locked: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked.'
```

BTW: make sure you remove the bit:

```
reasons:
    inactive: 'inactive'
    unconfirmed: 'unconfirmed'
    locked: 'locked'
```

Cheers, matt

Answer (score 3):

just adding as an answer that you can get an updated devise.en.yml as well as for other locales from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n